# C# HttpWebResponse gives back encoded response

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm making a `HttpWebRequest` to a server. This is in JSON. Now, the response is encoded and looks like this:

```
�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0��A� @ѻ�U�0l�u�\v�v�...
```

I can see that my request succeeded in Fiddler. And I can see the response of the server is the right one. But, also in fiddler it requires me to decode the answer first.

I have no idea how to decode this in C#.

Comment: Is it gzip encoded, or do you know what the encoding is? This is difficult to answer as-is, its like "here's a bunch of jarbled data in JSON format, tell me how to decode it", without knowing how its encoded, we can't say how to decode it...

Comment: Do you mean *encoded* (like UTF-16 vs. UTF-8), or *compressed* (like gzip), or *encrypted* (for security)? Is this an HTTPS call?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"). It's not encrypted for security, it might just be gzip.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I found a solution. AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of sample code that should do exactly what you want. **BatchCollection** in my case is my own object that maps to the JSON and so it can be mapped after its de-compressed.

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers = headers;
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batchCollection);

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(requestStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                compressionStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        BatchCollection batchOut = null;

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            var jsonOut = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            batchOut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BatchCollection>(jsonOut);
        }

        return batchOut;
```